# Get picture position in Apache POI from Excel xls HSSF

Tags: apache, apache-poi, image

My need is to get a picture data as bytes, then it's anchor details and finaly 
display the result on screen at target position and size for my users...

The API shows we can get a list of all pictures through workbook object like this:

```
List<HSSFPictureData> picturesData = workbook.getAllPictures();
```

and also we are able to fetch all anchors details (see HSSFClientAnchor details [here](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/A-newbie-question-how-to-get-image-position-td2294815.html)).

Problem is HSSFPicture.getPictureIndex() refered by an anchor does not match HSSFPictureData collection index of getAllPictures() method above...

...now the question is: how to map HSSFClientAnchor instances to specific HSSFPictureData instances or the opposite?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<HSSFShape> shapes  = this.tSheet.sheet().getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren();
        for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
        {
            if(shapes.get(i) instanceof HSSFPicture)
            {   
                HSSFPicture pic = (HSSFPicture) shapes.get(i);
                HSSFPictureData picdata = this.tSheet.sheet().getWorkbook().getAllPictures().get(pic.getPictureIndex());
                int pictureIndex = this.newSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture( picdata.getData(), picdata.getFormat());

this.newSheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createPicture((HSSFClientAnchor)pic.getAnchor()r, pictureIndex);

            }


        }
```

NOTE: 
Above code will read pic data from one sheet to another sheet 
this.tSheet.sheet() is source sheet 
this.newSheet is new sheet

Comment: As I said... Problem is HSSFPicture.getPictureIndex() refered by an anchor does not match HSSFPictureData collection index of getAllPictures() method above...