# Get an image and its position from excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is it possible to extract an image's information from an xls spreadsheet using Apache POI?

In one of my projects, I need to read some images from a .xls file. I can read all images together, but how can I get images position (like columns and rows number or coordinates)? Otherwise I can get images position but I can't know information, like picture name or extension or others, about a specific image at the positions found. How I can get images and positions too?

Here [read all images...](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images) and here [get images positions...](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/A-newbie-question-how-to-get-image-position-td2294815.html)

Comment: This might be relevant:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232844/get-picture-position-in-apache-poi-from-excel-xls-hssf

Also, this:

http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Parse-Excel-with-Picture-td2306811.html

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem and I found this: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Excel-image-sizes-td5582506.html

Answer (score 4):

Have a look here:

http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images

Sample:

```
List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();

for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {

    PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();

    String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();

    byte[] data = pict.getData();

    if (ext.equals("jpeg")) {

      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict.jpg");

      out.write(data);

      out.close();

    }
}
```

After this, you can use tools like ImageInfo which extends Magick to find out various configs. Yo can even convert images to different sizes.

Take a look at this class as well:

http://blog.jaimon.co.uk/simpleimageinfo/SimpleImageInfo.java.html

-- Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code will help)

```
    XSSFDrawing dp = workbook.getSheetAt(1).createDrawingPatriarch();
    List<XSSFShape> pics = dp.getShapes();
    XSSFPicture inpPic = (XSSFPicture)pics.get(0);

    XSSFClientAnchor clientAnchor = inpPic.getClientAnchor();
    inpPic.getShapeName(); // узнаю название картинки
    PictureData pict = inpPic.getPictureData();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict.jpg");
    byte[] data = pict.getData();
    out.write(data);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("col1: " + clientAnchor.getCol1() + ", col2: " + clientAnchor.getCol2() + ", row1: " + clientAnchor.getRow1() + ", row2: " + clientAnchor.getRow2());
    System.out.println("x1: " + clientAnchor.getDx1() + ", x2: " + clientAnchor.getDx2() +  ", y1: " + clientAnchor.getDy1() +  ", y2: " + clientAnchor.getDy2());
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you don`t want to use iterator (cause some times they are heavy)

```
public List readDrawing(Workbook workbook) throws Exception {
    List list = workbook.getAllPictures();

    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        PictureData picture = (PictureData) list.get(i);

        String ext = picture.suggestFileExtension();
        byte[] data = picture.getData();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("imageName" + "." + ext);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```