# .getAllPictures() Method doesn't get all the pictures in .xlsx excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I can't get all the pictures in .xlsx file that I made in MS Excel while when I used Google spreadsheet to create a .xlsx file it can read all the pictures that I inserted there.

My code is here:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("Sample.xlsx");
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();
```

Is there a way on how to read ALL the images in a .xlsx file which is done by MS Excel?

Comment: Did you see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577274/get-an-image-and-its-position-from-excel-file-using-apache-poi

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: im using version 3.8