# How to get images one by one from excel sheet and store them in folder using apache-poi?

Tags: java, excel

```
for (HSSFShape shape : sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren())
    {
        if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
        HSSFPicture picture = (HSSFPicture) shape;
        HSSFPictureData data = picture.getPictureData();
        byte data1[] = data.getData();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("image"+ i++ +".png");
        out.write(data1);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Here in this code `sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()` returns the list of images in byte array format. Instead of getting complete list I want an image cell by cell so that I can differentiate it by its cell/row number.

Comment: you mean you want for example cell at `C5` and get a picute if there is one?

Comment: yes exactly. @XtremeBaumer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577274/get-an-image-and-its-position-from-excel-file-using-apache-poi this might help you

Comment: That code also works similarly. he had used sheet.getAllPictures() instead of sheet.getDrawingPatrirach() which returns the list but I dont want list I want the data of the image in the particular cell of row.

Comment: well, AFAIK you can't get the picture via a cell reference, because the pictures are floating around and are not bound to any cell