# How to read image from excel using Poiji

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using ozlerhakan/poiji, and want to read image from excel like that:

```
 @ExcelCellName("Picture')
  private String picture;
```

This way doesn't work.

Is there any usage in ozlerhakan/poiji could support that?

Comment: [Get an image and its position from excel file using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577274/get-an-image-and-its-position-from-excel-file-using-apache-poi/24362610)

Comment: Pictures are not cell contents in `Excel`. They hover in a special layer over the cells and only are anchored to the cells. So even if they are over a column which has the text "Picture" in first row, they cannot be got from the cells in that column. Furthermore how shall a picture fit into a field `String picture`?